# NRF24I01 with antenna Communication Delay

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

I am doing my senior design project which is due in a week, I am currently using the NRF24I01 with antennas for both the transmitter and the receiver. I am building a robot that is suppose to climb a wall, the transmitter and receiver are to allow me to controller where it goes using a joystick. I will attach both codes. My current issue is when I push on the joystick one motor will run full speed while the other starts slow then catches up to full speed. After I let go of the joystick, the motors will still spin full speed for a minute trying to catch up for the delay in the beginning.

This is really frustrating because I am not well-versed with Arduino and I cannot figure out how to fix it, please help. 
Also I am using the radio.head library.

Reciever code:

```
#include <RHReliableDatagram.h>
#include <RH_NRF24.h>

#include <SPI.h>

#define CLIENT_ADDRESS 1
#define SERVER_ADDRESS 2

// Motor A connections analog 0 is digital 14 on arduino
int enA = 9;
int in1 = 2;
int in2 = 4;

// Motor B connections 
int enB = 5;
int in3 = 7;
int in4 = 6;

// Create an instance of the radio driver
RH_NRF24 RadioDriver;

// Sets the radio driver to NRF24 and the server address to 2
RHReliableDatagram RadioManager(RadioDriver, SERVER_ADDRESS); 

// Define a message to return if values recieved 
uint8_t ReturnMessage[] = "JoyStick Data Received";

// Define the Message Buffer
uint8_t buf[RH_NRF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];

void setup()
{
    // Set all the motor control pins to outputs
    pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);

    // Initilize RadioManager with defaults - 2.402 Ghz (channel 2), 2Mbps, 0dbm
    if (!RadioManager.init())
        Serial.println("init failed");
}


void loop()
{
    if (RadioManager.available())
    {
        // Wait for a message addressed to us from the client
        uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
        uint8_t from;

        if (RadioManager.recvfromAck(buf, &len, &from))
        {
//          Serial Print the values of joystick
//          Serial.print("got request from : 0x");
//          Serial.print(from, HEX);
//          Serial.print(": MotorA = "); 
//          Serial.print(buf[0]);
//          Serial.print("MotorB = ");
//          Serial.print(but[1]);
//          Serial.print(" Dir = ");
//          Serial.println(buf[2]);

            // Set Motor Direction
            if (buf[2] == 1)
            {
                // Motors are backwards
                digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
                digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
                digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
            }
            else
            {
                // Motors are forwards
                digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
                digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
                digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
            }

            // Drive Motors
            analogWrite(enA, buf[1]);
            analogWrite(enB, buf[0]);

            // Send a reply back to the orginitor client, check for error
            if (!RadioManager.sendtoWait(ReturnMessage, sizeof(ReturnMessage), from))
                Serial.println("sendtoWait failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Transceiver code:

```
#include <RHReliableDatagram.h>
#include <RH_NRF24.h>

#include <SPI.h>
#define joyVert  A0
#define joyHorz  A1

int joyposVert = 512;
int joyposHorz = 512;

#define CLIENT_ADDRESS 1
#define SERVER_ADDRESS 2

RH_NRF24 RadioDriver;

RHReliableDatagram RadioManager (RadioDriver, CLIENT_ADDRESS);

uint8_t motorcontrol[3]; 

uint8_t buf[RH_NRF24_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];



void setup() 
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    if (RadioManager.init())
        Serial.println("init failed");
    motorcontrol[2] = 0;
}

void loop() 
{
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    Serial.println("Reading motorcontrol values");
    joyposVert = analogRead(joyVert);
    joyposHorz = analogRead(joyHorz);


    //FORWARD & BACKWARD
    if (joyposVert < 460)
    {
        motorcontrol[2] = 1;
        motorcontrol[0] = map(joyposVert, 460, 0, 0, 255);
        motorcontrol[1] = map(joyposVert, 460, 0, 0, 255);

    }
    else if (joyposVert > 564)
    {
        motorcontrol[2] = 0;
        motorcontrol[0] = map(joyposVert, 564, 1023, 0, 255);
        motorcontrol[1] = map(joyposVert, 564, 1023, 0, 255);
    }
    else
    {
        motorcontrol[0] = 0;
        motorcontrol[1] = 0;
        motorcontrol[2] = 0;
    }

    // STEERING
    if (joyposHorz < 460)
    {
        // Move Left 
        joyposHorz = map(joyposHorz, 460, 0, 0, 255);

        motorcontrol[0] = motorcontrol[0] - joyposHorz;
        motorcontrol[1] = motorcontrol[1] + joyposHorz;

        // Dont exceed range of 0-255 for motor speeds
        if (motorcontrol[0] <   0) motorcontrol[0] = 0;
        if (motorcontrol[1] > 255) motorcontrol[1] = 255;

    }
    else if (joyposHorz > 564)
    {
        // Move Right
        joyposHorz = map(joyposHorz, 564, 1023, 0, 255);

        motorcontrol[0] = motorcontrol[0] + joyposHorz;
        motorcontrol[1] = motorcontrol[1] - joyposHorz;

        // Dont exceed range of 0-255 for motor speeds
        if (motorcontrol[0] > 255) motorcontrol[0] = 255;
        if (motorcontrol[1] <   0) motorcontrol[1] = 0;

    }
    // Adjust to prevent "buzzing" at very low speed
    if (motorcontrol[0] < 8)motorcontrol[0] = 0;
    if (motorcontrol[1] < 8)motorcontrol[1] = 0;

    // Display the Motor Control Values in the serial monitor.
//  Serial.print("Motor A: ");
//  Serial.print(motorcontrol[0]);
//  Serial.print(" - Motor B: ");
//  Serial.print(motorcontrol[1]); 
//  Serial.print(" - Direction: ");
//  Serial.println(motorcontrol[2]);

    // Send a message containing Motor Control data to manager_server
    if (RadioManager.sendtoWait(motorcontrol, sizeof(motorcontrol), SERVER_ADDRESS))
    {
        // Now wait for a reply from the server
        uint8_t len = sizeof(buf);
        uint8_t from;

        if (RadioManager.recvfromAckTimeout(buf, &len, 2000, &from))
        {
            Serial.print("got reply from :0x");
            Serial.print(from, HEX);
            Serial.print(": ");
            Serial.println((char*)buf);
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("No reply, is nrf24_reliable_datagram_server running?");
        }
    }
    else
        Serial.println("senttoWait failed");

//  delay(10);  //Wait a bit before next transmission
}
```

Comment: First thing to do is to open your code in the Arduino IDE and press Control-T to format the code and line up the blocks.  I don't know how you can try to see the logic in this with code wandering all over the page.  When real coders write with the nice neat blocks, we don't do that just to make it pretty.  It makes it easier to read as well.  The IDE does it for you so there's really no excuse.  Oftentimes that exercise alone will make the problem stand out like a sore thumb.

Comment: Please find out, when exactly the message gets send by the transceiver and when the full message is received by the receiver (finding out, which part of the code causes the delay). You can light an LED right before sending the message, turning it off afterwards. and on the receiver you can turn on an led, when the message got fully received. That way you can determine, if the timing problem really lies in the radio code, or if it is something else.

Comment: @Delta_G It is lined up in my code but when I put it in here I just manually spaced it so I know it is not great to look at. But in my actual code it is.

Comment: @chrisl When I look at the serial monitor most of the time the messages are sent and received immediately.  For some reason sometimes it will report to me that the message failed to send.

Comment: @jsotola The motors work fine when they are connected to a direct power source. The transmitter and receiver have some delay which affects the motors, which is why it will spend for a while without me using the joystick. Using deductive reasoning and some help from a professor I understand my issues are with the communication between the two NRF24I01 I just do not understand what it is.

Comment: @jsotola Yes but the main issue is the delay when I move the controller. It does not matter if I move the motor side to side or forward or backwards the same issue will occur... or another common issue if i hold the controller in one spot (forward, backwards left, or right) the motors may not start I keep holding the stick for many a minute or 30 seconds then the motors will start. After I let go of the joystick the motors will still spin for a little longer than the time I help the joy stick in that position.

Comment: @jsotola I kind of understand what you are saying. If it help I am using a motor driver to control the motors. For the issue you are saying is there a resource you know of that can help. Right now I am using the transmitter code that connects the joystick to move the individual motors so I have a full 360 scope of movement.  This project has deemed to be very difficult and my knowledge of code is not that strong so I am having to teach myself so my understand of the components responsibilities are lacking.

Comment: solve the problem in steps .... the transmission delays do not really matter right now .... transmit only the joystick position of only one axis .... on the receiver, move both the motors at the same time and in the same direction .... choose the forward or backward depending on the joystick value received  ..... your code is pretty close to that already

Comment: I am only using one joystick to control both the motors would this make a difference to your suggestion?

Comment: a joystick usually has X and Y .... send only one .... that way you have only simple data to deal with

Comment: I ditched the RH_NRF lib due to x problems when used in applications like yours, I now use an optimized high speed nRF24L01 library Give it a try https://github.com/nRF24/RF24

Comment: I would suggest changing your code so that you only send any data when the position of the joystick actually changes, rather than blasting data constantly flooding the link.

Comment: @Majenko this does not work (sending only when changes) if you use it as RC equipment. In my boat /flying models this acts as fail safe/heartbeat -no signal from the remote stop engines or initiate failure procedure. (Just as an info for the special case usage in remote controled models)

Comment: Periodic sending is fine. Flooding a digital link could cause problems. A regular heartbeat packet one every 100ms or something shouldn't flood the link and give you your failsafe.